# Is there a significant benefit to partitioning rather than pivoting when (quick)sorting?

Tags: optimization, quicksort, idioms

In each phase of the Quick-Sort algorithm, a pivot is chosen, and the data is bi-partitioned into elements below and above the pivot (and some tie breaking for being equal to it).

Now, each pivoting requires a pass over the data. Also, the variance of the pivot's relative position around being the median element is pretty high. Instead, one could conceivably take a sample of k elements, i.i.d. , and partition the data into k+1 parts, using the sample elements as boundaries for the different parts. And while some parts may be too small or too big, most should be fine; and the rest will need some correction (e.g. by counting) but that should be doable.

I've not tried such an approach out over (binary) Quick-Sort but was wondering if such an approach is used in practice at all, and if there's actually benefit to doing so.

PS - If you can say something about the amenability to parallelization (using AVX-512 on a CPU, with a Xeon Phi, with a GPU etc.) - that would be extra helpful.

Comment: Apparently, this is still an open question in CS research. I found [this pdf](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/180/1/012051/pdf). Their experiments show that the improvement over 2-pivot quicksort (java) is not that much.

Comment: @jrook: So, that paper is from a first-time-ever conference. Is it legit? That is, is it serious or one of those third-and-fourth-tier affairs? ... ah, never mind, I'll skim through the paper anyway.

Comment: I also found [this paper](https://dl-acm-org.ezproxy1.lib.asu.edu/citation.cfm?doid=2997037.2963102) (requires access) which seems to give better performance for a higher number of pivots. The problem is the general complexity formula hasn't been solved analytically for pivots > 4. So there is no option but to give empirical estimates.

Comment: @jrook: But you don't need a theoretical analysis to implement it and compare its performance against few-pivots quicksort...